# Split a Matlab table in several tables dynamically

Tags: matlab

I am working in MATLAB and I did not find yet a way to split a table T in different tables {T1,T2,T3,...} *dynamically*. What I mean with *dynamic* is that it must be done based on some conditions of the table T that are not known a priori. For now, I do it in a *non-dynamic* way with the following code (I hard-code the number of tables I want to have).

```
%% Separate data of table T in tables T1,T2,T3
starting_index = 1;
T1 = T(1:counter_simulations(1),:);
starting_index = counter_simulations(1)+1;
T2 = T(starting_index:starting_index+counter_simulations(2)-1,:);
starting_index = starting_index + counter_simulations(2);
T3 = T(starting_index:starting_index+counter_simulations(3)-1,:);
```

Any ideas on how to do it dynamically? I would like to do something like that:

```
for (i=1:number_of_tables_to_create)
   T{i} = ...
end
```

**EDIT:** the variable `counter_simulations` is an array containing the number of rows I want to extract for each table. Example: `counter_simulations(1)=200` will mean that the first table will be T1= `T(1:200, :)`. If `counter_simulations(2)=300` the first table will be T1= `T(counter_simulations(1)+1:300, :)` and so on.

I hope I was clear.

Should I use cell arrays instead of tables maybe?

Thanks!

Comment: Definetly do not create variables dynamically. Cell array is the way to go. However we can't help more because you have not described how you split your table.

Comment: Let's say the table has 4 columns, and you want to end up with 3 new tables. How should the original table be split?

Comment: I don't know why either of you think the question doesn't give a clear explanation of the expected output. Apart from specifying the contents of `counter_simulations` (which can easily be assumed to contain integers that add up to the number of rows in `T` or less) the example given does a very tidy job of explaining the intended output.

Comment: Hi, thanks for all your comments. I added an EDIT to the question. I hope that now it is clear what I meant with `counter_simulations`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the example you give, where `counter_simulations` contains a list of the number of rows to take from `T` in each of the output tables, MATLAB's [`mat2cell`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) function actually implements this behaviour directly:

```
T = mat2cell(T,counter_simulations);
```

While you haven't specified the contents of `counter_simulations`, it's clear that if `sum(counter_simulations) > height(T)` the example would fail. If `sum(counter_simulations) < height(T)` (and so your desired output doesn't contain the last row(s) of `T`) then you would need to add a final element to `counter_simulations` and then discard the resulting output table:

```
counter_simulations(end+1) = height(T) - sum(counter_simulations);
T = mat2cell(T,counter_simulations);
T(end) = [];
```

Whether this solution applies to all examples of

> some conditions of the table T that are not known a priori

you ask for in the question depends on the range of conditions you actually mean; for a broad enough interpretation there will not be a general solution but you might be able to narrow it down if `mat2cell` performs too specific a job for your actual problem.

Comment: Thanks @Will, I will try to implement what you suggested and come back here asap.

Comment: Thanks, it worked flawlessly, I forgot about the `mat2cell` function